# How to open my partially closed ear?

Tags: hearing, ear, waking-up

Some weeks back, my left ear was closed partially when I woke up in the morning.Now I hear less from that ear. What could have happed to my ear? Is there any way to open it?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is you should go to see a doctor. Your primary care physician can look deep into your ear to see if there is anything lodged in it. It may be a build up of wax, or debris. If so, your doctor can clean it out. If there is nothing blocking your ear drum, and the feeling of blockage continues you should see a specialist.  You could also have an ear infection that could be causing some inflammation. The doctor may prescribe ear drops, an oral antibiotic, or even a nasal spray to help with you  These physicians are called Ear, Nose & Throat (ENT) doctors. They can test to see if there is a problem with how your ear is working.  Here is a web site that explains how the ear works. It is a remarkable and complex instrument. Protect it. Good luck.

https://www.hearinglink.org/your-hearing/how-the-ear-works/

Comment: Thank you. It was just  wax and I have cleaned it with my finger.